# C++ “Unable to read memory” when accessing pointer object from inherited class

Tags: c++, pointers, object, inheritance

I have this error:

```
Exception thrown at 0x0108C6E9 in myprojectname.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000028.
```

However, this only happens when I call a function from the base class via the derived class.

I need a pointer to the space object because my base class also needs that. I am not sure if this is needed.

This is how I call the functions of the base(Player) class:

```
space->getEnemy().drawPlayer(); //FIRST I GET THE OBJECT OF THE DERIVED(ENEMY CLASS) AND THAN I CALL A FUNCTION FROM THE BASE CLASS(PLAYER CLASSS)
```

The error message "Unable to read memory" happens in getter functions in a class that the base class needs(for example a pointer to the window).

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

I initialize that space pointer to my import class named Space, in every class of my project. The program works fine with those space pointers if I don't call the inherited stuff of Enemy class.

**EDIT:**

I found out that the object to the (very important) Space class, is NULL in the base class. The enemy class space object is not NULL, but the space object of the class it inherits from, is NULL. Does anyone know how an inherited pointer object can be NULL?

A picture to make it clearer:

http://prntscr.com/9btfim

**EDIT 2 MY CURRENT CODE:**

Enemy.h (THE DERIVED CLASS)

```
#pragma once

class Space;
class Enemy : public Player{
public:
    void updateEnemy();

private:

};
```

Enemy.cpp

```
#include "Space.h"
#include "Enemy.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include <iostream>

void Enemy::updateEnemy(){
    if (space == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "null"; //IT PRINTS NULL
    }
}
```

A part of player.h (THE BASE CLASS)

```
class Space; //forward declaration
public:
    void init(Space * s);
protected:
    Space * space;
```

A part of player.cpp

```
void Player::init(Space * s){ //INITIALIZING SPACE CLASS OBJECT
    space = s;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show correct current code.  What you posted had `space` lines commented out, but debugger output showed they were not commented out.  Then your comments (on my answer) imply you removed one of those commented out lines and the other is not working.  You are making me guess too much about what you actually tested.

Comment: @JSF I edited my question with the current code.

Comment: But you did not update that debug display, which still shows the two copies of `space` only one of which is zero.  Assuming there is now only one copy and it is zero, then why wasn't `Player::init` called for `Enemy`.  Do you also have an `Enemy::init` hiding it and missing the usual idiom of calling the hidden base class function?

Comment: @JSF No because I thought Enemy class would inherit Player class including the pointer object to Space class.

Comment: So you seem to be saying you did not make the mistake of defining an incorrect `Enemy::init` function.  So which point in your code was supposed to call `Player::init` for the Enemy object and why didn't that work?  (You are still leaving out the critical details).

Comment: There is no Enemy::init actually. I thought when Enemy class inherits Player class(and the object of Space in the player class is correct by the way), Enemy class also has space object of player class. Player::init is called by space class, which gives "this" as argument to player::init. I hope I explained clearly.

Comment: That was already clear and explaining isn't showing.  The symptom implies that part of your code is broken.  You are describing it as it is intended to work.  You could add some trace output there to prove it isn't broken or show us enough of the relevant code that we can see that isn't broken.  My guess is you have misunderstood having two Player objects.  One is just a Player, the other is part of Enemy, and `init` was called for just the first.

Comment: Even deeper into guessing your intent:  You wanted one copy of `space` shared across all instances of `Player` and don't yet understand the difference between a class and an object.  That kind of sharing works if the variable is declared `static` **and** defined outside the class definition.  See details I added inside my earlier answer.

Comment: @JSF IT WORKS!! I know I sound like an 8 years old(Im only 15), but thank you so much! I did not initialize the space object for the inherited player class as you said. Thank you so much, I learned a lot :D
Btw, I once tried to do it with static but that didnt go really well so I gave up. But anyways, Thanks dude :)

Answer (score 0):

Both your Player object and your Enemy object declare a

```
Space * space;
```

So `Enemy::space` hides `Player::space` so when you init `Enemy::space`, `Player::space` remains zero.

It is almost certainly a mistake to declare another `Space * space` in the `Enemy` class.  You should be using the one in the `Player` class.  I expect the one in the `Player` class was `private` so you can't use it.  But having another one doesn't fix that.  Either change it from `private` to `protected` or make all accesses through an accessor function.

Edit:  Wild guess, you want one `Space * space` shared by all instances of the `Player` class.  To do that:  Inside the definition of `Player` you have:

```
static Space * space;
```

and elsewhere outside the definition of `Player` (in some cpp file) you need:

```
Space* Player::space;
```

Comment: So I have to remove the Space * space; from Enemy class?

Comment: Remove that from Enemy **AND** make the one in Player accessible to Enemy.

Comment: Did you remember to recompile?  It would also help to post the relevant parts of the code, rather than make us deduce things about the code from the data in the debugger watch window.  But since the problem was highlighted so well by what you posted in that watch window and you theoretically fixed **that** what does that window look like now?

Comment: I checked it, and the space object in the Player class accessd from the Enemy(derived) class is nullptr.

Comment: Try - Add a std::cout of the 'this' pointer into the ctor of the two classes.  Then figure out why one is null.  (ctor not called?)

Comment: In which two classes? The enemy class does not have space object, it inherits the one from Player class. It does, right?